# How to make a checkbox show/hide text with onChange event

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am working on a checkbox that shows a new textbox when clicked. It's just two textboxes where one of them is hidden. When the checkbox is checked it shows the hidden textbox and hides the already enabled textbox.

I am using the onChange event to show/hide, but I can only manage to turn it on once. And since I'm just starting out using Javascript, I haven't really worked out all the variables on how make two onChange events for the same checkbox (*. I am using onChange as it reacts to the checkbox itself, while onClick somehow only react to everything except the checkbox.

Another problem is that I'm using Wix Corvid to program it, and I don't get any functioning name or ID on the checkbox.

```
$w.onReady(function (){ 
$w('#checkboxGroup1').onChange((event)=> {
$w('#text108').show();
$w('#text106').hide();  
})
});
```

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/x0gon2a9/4/

`<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="chckbox1" checked="true"> checkbox1
    <input type="text" id="input-1" value="input-1">
    <input type="text" id="input-2" value="input-2" >`

```
 if ($("#checkbox").is(":checked")) {
 $("#input-1").hide();
}else {
$("#input-1").show();
}
});

$("#checkbox").click(function(){
if ($("#checkbox").is(":checked")) { 
$("#input-1").hide();
$("#input-2").show();
}else {
$("#input-1").show();
$("#input-2").hide();
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if it's checked or not first:

```
$w.onReady(function (){ 
$w('#checkboxGroup1').change((event)=> {
if($w('#checkboxGroup1').prop('checked') == true)
   $w('#text108').show();
else
   $w('#text106').hide();  
})
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I get this error when pressing the checkbox https://i.imgur.com/3JzbCmC.png

Is there anything I can replace the prop with?

Comment: Sorry, i've updated my answer. it should be `$w(this)` not `$(this)`

Comment: It got me somewhere, but now I get another error: https://i.imgur.com/Y4RRU72.png

Thank you for taking your time to respond despite it not working as intended.

Comment: I am not sure how `$w` works but in this case, it's ok to replace `this` with `$w('#checkboxGroup1')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use class selector to add `EventListener` on the checkboxs and show hide the input based on that.

Here is the sample working code in vanilla javascript.

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {

    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {

        const id = this.dataset.inputId;

        if (this.checked === true) {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
});
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-input-id="input-1" value="chckbox1"> checkbox1
    <input type="text" id="input-1" value="input-1" style="display: none">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-input-id="input-2" value="chckbox1"> checkbox2
    <input type="text" id="input-2" value="input-2" style="display: none">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.target.checked`

```
$w.onReady(function (){ 
  $w('#checkboxGroup1').onChange((event)=> {
    if (event.target.checked) {
       $w('#text108').show();
    } else {
      $w('#text106').hide();  
    }
  });
});
```